# Exponent Law: Negative Exponents Division

Tags: exponentiation

I'm trying to relearn high-school maths after years of decay. This is a very basic exponent law question.

How can I prove the following in a step-by-step fashion:

$$
\biggl(\frac{7^3}{3^8}\biggl)^{-2} = 
\frac{3^{16}}{7^6}
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go by as follows:

Using exponentiation rules

$$
\Big(\frac{7^3}{3^8}\Big)^{-2}=\Big(\frac{7^3}{3^8}\Big)^{2\cdot (-1)}=
$$
$$
=\Big(\frac{7^{3\cdot 2}}{3^{8\cdot 2}}\Big)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{7^{3\cdot 2}}{3^{8\cdot 2}}}=
$$
$$
=\frac{3^{8\cdot 2}}{7^{3\cdot 2}}=\frac{3^{16}}{7^{6}}.
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer.